# get generated id before writing to db

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have 2 tables, products, and product_photos. I need to insert data to both tables in one transaction.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products", schema = "my_schema")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    ...
    //getter + setter + constructor
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_photos", schema = "my_schema")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductPhoto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Integer productId;

    ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the id of the Product before writing the entity to DB in order to put it on ProductPhoto (column product_id)?

Comment: It is not possible to get that id as that ID is generated when the entity is written into database. That means if you do not set the id then it will automatically use the generation strategy to generate a id for you. If you want to get the id then you have to save the product entity first. Once saved the entity will have an id assigned to it. If you want product_id in product_photo why not just just map it with onetoone or onetomany mapping. It will solve your issue,

Comment: Create a new table to hold generated sequence(Id), and remove `@GeneratedValue` from id in Product class. And assign the generated value from the new table `sequence(Id)` and assign `id` value with it.

Comment: If this will help and you agree it, I will share full answer with sample code. @rico

Comment: You should create a @OneToMany/@ManyToOne relationship between these two entities, then Hibernate will take care of proper setting ids in both entities.

Comment: thanks guys. I finally can make it with using @OneToOne relation between them